# Change GitHub account back

Tags: github

I have a GitHub account, and I created a new one (temporary, not to replace the old one).
Now, I try to go back to my old account, I changed the email with `git config --global user.email = "myuser@email.com"` tried to push to an old repo I have connected to my old account, and It says `"Permission to X denied to NEW_GITHUB_NAME"`
What do I need to do to get back my old account?

Comment: Remove the `=` equal sign from the `git config` command.

Comment: It didn't work. Is it possible to just keep the two accounts and switch them? Like one for personal projects and one for work projects?